# Ambiguous column with MyBatis SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, mybatis

I have an error with my query below. Could you please help me?

The error is caused by an ambiguous column. I have an idea by I am not sure.

I think the error is the WorkUID column in here (ambiguous):

```
<isNotEmpty property="uids">
    AND WorkUID IN
    <iterate  property="uids" open="(" close=")" conjunction=",">
      #uids[]#
    </iterate>
  </isNotEmpty>
```

Here is the error:

```
Cause: SqlMapClient operation; SQL [];   
--- The error occurred while applying a parameter map.  
--- Check the getData-InlineParameterMap.  
--- Check the statement (query failed).  
--- Cause: java.sql.SQLException: Ambiguous column name 'WorkUID'.; nested exception is com.ibatis.common.jdbc.exception.NestedSQLException:   
--- The error occurred while applying a parameter map.  
--- Check the getData-InlineParameterMap.  
--- Check the statement (query failed).  
--- Cause: java.sql.SQLException: Ambiguous column name 'WorkUID'.;
net.extraction.etl.exception.DAOException: Getting work UID by release datetime.
Cause: org.springframework.dao.TransientDataAccessResourceException: SqlMapClient operation; SQL [];   
--- The error occurred while applying a parameter map.  
--- Check the getData-InlineParameterMap.
```

Here is the query:

```
<select id="getData" resultClass="java.lang.Integer" parameterClass="java.util.Map" >
    <![CDATA[
            SELECT xrn.WorkUID
            FROM
            (SELECT uow.WorkUID,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY wsh.WorkUID ORDER BY wsh.DT DESC) AS rnk
            FROM UnitWork uow
            INNER JOIN SigHist sh ON  sh.SigUID = uow.SigUID
            INNER JOIN DataCell d ON d.WorkUID = uow.WorkUID
            INNER JOIN WorkStatHist wsh ON (wsh.WorkUID = uow.WorkUID
                                                 AND wsh.WorkUID = d.WorkUID
                                                            AND 8 =
                                                    (SELECT TOP 1 StatusUID
                                                    FROM WorkStatHist(NOLOCK)
                                                    WHERE WorkUID = uow.workUID
                                                    ORDER BY DT DESC))
      WHERE (uow.ReleasedDT > #fromDate#)
            OR (sh.UpdatedDT > #fromDate#)
            AND d.EffectiveTo >= GETDATE() + 1
            ]]>
    <dynamic>
      <isNotEmpty property="toDate">
        <![CDATA[
                        AND d.EffectiveTo < #toDate#
                    ]]>
      </isNotEmpty>
      <isNotEmpty property="uids">
        AND WorkUID IN
        <iterate  property="uids" open="(" close=")" conjunction=",">
          #uids[]#
        </iterate>
      </isNotEmpty>
    </dynamic>
    <![CDATA[
    ) xrn
            WHERE xrn.rnk=1
        ]]>
  </select>
```

Comment: What language is this...?  There is clearly another language being used besides SQL Server.  Please tag your question appropriately.  And rename your title, please.

Comment: You don't have this qualified... `AND WorkUID IN`. In  your `Where` statement after `<isNotEmpty property="uids">`

Comment: Thanks for your reply all, it is a sql query written with mybatis. WEI_DBA, Could you please give reexplain what do you find wrong in that query because I did not catch your explanation above. Thank you very much guys

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with `MyBatis` at all, so I can't speak for that part of the code, but it appears that your issue is with the following section:

```
<isNotEmpty property="uids">
    AND WorkUID IN
    <iterate  property="uids" open="(" close=")" conjunction=",">
      #uids[]#
    </iterate>
</isNotEmpty>
```

Particularly the `AND WorkUID IN` part.

There are multiple tables in your query that have `WorkUID` as a column, so it doesn't know which table to pull it from.

Seeing that it is being used as a `JOIN` constraint for every table, it doesn't particularly matter which table we tell it to look in.

Changing it to the following should clear up that error:

```
<isNotEmpty property="uids">
    AND uow.WorkUID IN
    <iterate  property="uids" open="(" close=")" conjunction=",">
      #uids[]#
    </iterate>
</isNotEmpty>
```

Comment: + 1 for comment: Seeing that it is being used as a JOIN constraint for every table, it doesn't particularly matter which table we tell it to look in.  and right answer.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help. I have fixed it by following Siyual's guidance.

Comment: Hello again everyone, can I ask a last question about the query above? how can I do to add a new condition like: WHERE wsh.WorkUID = uow.workUID  AND uow.WorkUID IN(55) in my where condition for my SELECT TOP 1 StatusUID   FROM WorkStatHist(NOLOCK). It doesn t take into account my new condition